# Naming Class.new

Tags: ruby, class

Why is it assigning a name/constant to Class.new behaves this way?

```
c = Class.new #=> <Class:0xnnnnnnn>
puts c  #=> <Class:0xnnnnnnn>

b = c
puts b #=> <Class:0xnnnnnnn>

NewClass = c   #=> NewClass  <shouldn't it be same as above #=> <Class:0xnnnnnnn>
puts c  #=> NewClass  <and now c has a name although it was not the left operand above>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The latter is equivalent to using `kernel::const_set`

semantically `class NewClass` is equivalent to

```
c = Class.new
Kernel::const_set :NewClass, c
```

and assigning to a constant ie `NewClass = c` is semantically equivalent to

```
Kernel::const_set :NewClass,c
```

so when you write

```
c = Class.new
NewClass = c
```

it's semantically the same as writing

```
class NewClass
```

Answer (score 4):

Because that's how ruby works. (*my second answer today that starts with this sentence :)*)

You can create dynamic anonymous classes and use them. But upon first assignment to a constant, the class takes the constant's name as its own name. And that's final, you can't change the name now.

Answer (score 0):

NewClass is a reference to a constant. Any reference that starts with a capital letter is a constant and kept that way during execution.

If you were to call '.object_id' on any of those variables, they would be the same.

If you call 'Module.constants', you'd see NewClass in the list of top level constants. The reference will pull from there.

Answer (score 0):

That's just how [`Module#name`](http://Ruby-Doc.Org/core-2.0/Module.html#method-i-name) and [`Module#inspect`](http://Ruby-Doc.Org/core-2.0/Module.html#method-i-inspect)/[`Module#to_s`](http://Ruby-Doc.Org/core-2.0/Module.html#method-i-to_s) are defined.